# WPF DataBinding does not update property (just only one time at startup)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I´m having some trouble binding some items attributes.

I have comboboxes and a buttons in a itemscontrol. The combobox is for searching Localities by name. Thats why when the combobox is created, the property IsEditable is true, in order to let the user enter a name, and then press left-control to search that string in the database via WCF.

Then, when the combobox ItemSource.Count is al least 1, I block the combobox by setting IsEditable = false (using the DataBinding of the button). Thats when the button have to change the visibility from hidden to visible, because pressing the button set IsEditable to true again, and ables the user to input a name to search.

To achieve this, I have binded the combobox IsEditable with the button Visibility attribute, and used the following converter, which works:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class VisibilityToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible ? false : true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I said, the left control button search the localities, for that I´m using the keydown event:

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
        LocationServiceClient locationService = new LocationServiceClient();

        if (cbx != null)
        {
            cbx.ItemsSource = locationService.SeachLocalities(new SearchLocalitiesRequest { Search = cbx.Text, MaxItems = 20 }).Localities;
            cbx.DisplayMemberPath = "LocalityName";
            localityCombobox = cbx;
            cbx.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**As the Items of the Combobox changed, wouldn´t that have to affect the binding of the Button visibility?
The binding uses this converter, which works too, but only executes once, when I run the app. Thats the problem I´m having, it just does not update the button visibility, and leaves it on Hidden:**

```
public class ItemsSourceCountToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = (int)value > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        return b;       
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This the image of the control, it might help you to get what I say:

[image]

Just in case, this is the xaml i used:

```
<ComboBox Name ="cbxLocality" Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding LocalityName}" IsEditable="{Binding ElementName= btnRemoveLocality, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBooleanConverter}}" KeyDown="ComboBox_KeyDown">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalityName}"/>
                <TextBlock  FontSize="10">
                    <Run Text="CP: "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding ZipCode}"/>
                    <Run Text=" | "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Province.ProvinceName}"/>          
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<Button Name ="btnRemoveLocality" Content="x" Visibility="{Binding ElementName= cbxLocality, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceCountToVisibilityConverter}}" Click="Button_Click_3"></Button>
```

Comment: your variable 'localities' is going out of scope!

Comment: @GarryVass what do you mean?

Comment: You have an observable collection declared as a local variable.  The binding engine cannot see the getter for it in order to make a proper subscription to the observable's events!

Comment: @GarryVass I changed it now. I assign directly the array that the service returns. But I´m still having the same issue

Comment: Sadly, it's getting worse.  Create an observable collection *public property* with a getter and setter, and make that your items source.

Comment: @GarryVass the problem is that I have a dynamic count of comboboxes in that ItemsControl. If I have to declare one ObservableCollection for each of them, I wouldn´t know how many I have to create.

Comment: Solve the problem with one combo box.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Does it work to call .DataBind() on cbx when changing ItemSource?</s>

Edit: I would bind the visibility for path Items.Count, instead of just Items, and make the converter handle the integer instead of the Item-list. Because the Count-property triggers the PropertyChanged-event, and the list itself will not if an element is added/removed.

Edit 2: Declare the ObservableCollection of you items as a public property outside the method itself, so it will have public scope. And set it as ItemsSource. Then you won't have to change the ItemSource-property, only the collection itself.

Comment: Hi, there is not method .DataBind() in the WPF control.. Or at least does not appears..

Comment: Hey that helped! But it is NOT executing the code when the Items count is zero and the button visibility has to be set to Visible. Actually, is it not executing the code when the itemsource changes.

Comment: Great! What do you mean? Write the converter so it can be executed anytime, and handle the zero-count inside the converter code - or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: What I mean, is that when the ItemSource change, the databinding is not executing the converter. I don´t know why :/

Comment: See edit 2. You should have the collection as ItemsSource from the beginning, and not have to change that. Later you only have to assign the collection a new value, and not reassign the ItemsSource.

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem with that.. I have a itemcontrol with many of those comboboxes. They are dynamic, thats why I dont know how many observablecollections i will have. I will try defining one globally though.

Comment: Ok, try it to see if it works. Maybe you could have an ObservableCollection containing all your ObservableCollections used in the itemcontrol?